# PDO Driver is not found in react folder

Tags: php, pdo, driver

I thought I would have a look at react because I was looking for a way to display live results on the website.

I would like to use react as frontend and php as backend. My problem now is when I try to create a connection with pdo, I get the following error message:

Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in...

My folder looks like this:

[image]

Do I have a big error in thinking or what could it be?
I have made all possible attempts to fix the error, but everything is of no use.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

I have tried all the solutions on the site here under the same error, and searched on Youtube for solutions but in vain. I hope for clarity on my thinking or how to fix the error.

Comment: You need to enable the `pdo_mysql` extension in your `php.ini`. It has nothing to do with what folder you are currently in, it is in the PHP directory.

Comment: Where i find the php.ini? I have one in the xampp folder?

Comment: Try `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` (replace `C:\xampp` with wherever you have installed XAMPP, if it's not the same).

Comment: Running phpinfo() in php will show you where it is. Remember to restart the webserver after modifying it

Comment: I already done this but phpinfo() says no directory and no value for pdo driver. And in the php.ini is all right but it dont work.